# System dependency visualisation

Tags: dependencies, requirements-management

We have a complex system with multiple requirements driven dependencies to stakeholders and others systems.

We are looking for a tool to analyse the influences of changes on our system with respect to the surrounding environment. Including modelling and some kind of graphical representation.

E.g. Changing a specific aspect of the system will enable to use xy but will destroy a former existing dependency.

While MS Windows is preferred, don't mind the OS.